# Dell PE 1850 stuck on boot, can't enter Setup

Tags: boot, dell-poweredge

I acquired a PowerEdge 1850 from a friend who was moving away.  I'm trying to get it to boot, but after the DELL loading screen, it only outputs:

```
One 3.20 GHz Processor, Processor Bus: 800 MHz, L2 cache: 2 MB
Remote Access Controller detected
```

Nothing else happens. The amber error light is flashing and there are no beep codes.

I've tried holding F2 to enter Setup, and `F2 = Setup` becomes `Entering Setup`, but as soon as the loading screen ends, the server starts beeping, and this continues for as long as I hold the key.

Comment: There are several amber lights that can blink. Which one is it? See [Indicators, Messages, and Codes: Dell PowerEdge 1850 Systems Installation and Troubleshooting Guide](http://www.serwerydell.eu/1850/it/r1712c20)

Comment: @DavidPostill The Amber System Status Indicator.

Comment: "The amber system status indicator flashes when the system needs attention due to a problem with power supplies, fans, system temperature, or hard drives."

Comment: @Moab That doesn't tell me what the problem is. That's 4 things that relate to the problem, and I don't know which one it is, nor what is wrong with it.

Comment: That is why it is a comment and not an answer, no way we can answer here, you will have to eliminate each potential problems (4) on your end. No way we can trouble shoot it for you.